# ASP.Net MVC to ASFS Call Throwing Remote Certificate Error

Tags: asp.net-mvc, azure, asp.net-identity, single-sign-on, adfs

I configured an ADFS service in one of my Azure VMs. I created a free

> certificate using this tool, https://github.com/Crypt32/PSPKI,  and
>   configured it under Trusted Root in that VM. I also able to run and
>   login inside that VN using /adfs/ls/idpinitiatedSignOn.aspx. I also
>   added "https://localhost:44360/" as a trusted inside ADFS. Then I
>   created a local ASP.NET application which is running as
>   https://localhost:44360/ and using
>   "https://adfsvm.centralus.cloudapp.azure.com/FederationMetadata/2007-06/FederationMetadata.xml"
>   as a metadata Ref. I could able to download this metadata file in my
>   machine, once skipped the security warning.
>
> My issue is that Once running the application, screen throws the error
>   as "The remote certificate is invalid according to the validation
>   procedure.".

[image]

> I confirmed that on ADFS server, it didn't hit and no logs. But in my
>   local machine some logs are there like below.

IDX20804: Unable to retrieve document from: '[PII is hidden by default. Set the 'ShowPII' flag in IdentityModelEventSource.cs to true to reveal it.]'. at Microsoft.IdentityModel.Protocols.HttpDocumentRetriever.d__8.MoveNext() --- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown --- at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task) at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task) at Microsoft.IdentityModel.Protocols.WsFederation.WsFederationConfigurationRetriever.d__4.MoveNext() --- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown --- at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task) at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task) at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ValidateEnd(Task task) at Microsoft.IdentityModel.Protocols.ConfigurationManager`1.d__24.MoveNext() An error occurred while sending the request. at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task) at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task) at Microsoft.IdentityModel.Protocols.HttpDocumentRetriever.d__8.MoveNext() The underlying connection was closed: Could not establish trust relationship for the SSL/TLS secure channel. at System.Net.HttpWebRequest.EndGetResponse(IAsyncResult asyncResult) at System.Net.Http.HttpClientHandler.GetResponseCallback(IAsyncResult ar) The remote certificate is invalid according to the validation procedure. at System.Net.TlsStream.EndWrite(IAsyncResult asyncResult) at System.Net.PooledStream.EndWrite(IAsyncResult asyncResult) at System.Net.ConnectStream.WriteHeadersCallback(IAsyncResult ar) 
      https://localhost:44360/

> Any lead here to troubleshoot more would be appreciated.

Comment: More updates as I set IdentityModelEventSource.ShowPII = true; and now it's showing correct exception as <Data>IDX20804: Unable to retrieve document from: 'https://adfsvm.centralus.cloudapp.azure.com/FederationMetadata/2007-06/FederationMetadata.xml'.
   at Microsoft.IdentityModel.Protocols.HttpDocumentRetriever.&lt;GetDocumentAsync&gt;d__8.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task). I able to download that XML, after skipping browser security warning

Comment: This is self-signed so needs to be trusted on your PC.

Comment: Yes, I just exported that license to local and now it's started working